# Confusion setting up a simple tomcat6 clustering on ubuntu 12.04 using mod_jk: status page won't show

Tags: ubuntu, tomcat, load-balancing, cluster, mod-jk

am a little confused when setting up 2 tomcat6 instances cluster in a clean ubuntu server 12.04. i didn't install default `tomcat6` i used `tomcat6-user`'s `tomcat6-instance-create` to create 2 instances. I'm using [blogs.encodo.ch](http://blogs.encodo.ch/news/view_article.php?id=18) tutorial, unfortunately i haven't come across any tutorial using ubuntu with how `apache2` is configured like ubuntu 12.o4. i mean by that , the structure of `sites-available/enabled` folder and `mods-available/enabled` that ubuntu uses.
i've installed `libapache2-mod-jk` and `mods-enabled` has jk.load,jk.conf.

`server instance-1 uses port 8081 for http, port 8009 for ajp with jvmRoute="worker1" and instance-2 uses port 8082 for http, port 8010 for ajp with jvmRoute="worker2"`

```
#/etc/apache2/workers.propeties
 worker.list=loadbalancer,jk-status

#setup instance-1
worker.instance-1.port=8009
worker.instance-1.host=localhost
worker.instance-1.type=ajp13
#worker.instance-1.lbfactor=50

#setup instance-2
worker.instance-2.port=8010
worker.instance-2.host=localhost
worker.instance-2.type=ajp13
#worker.instance-2.lbfactor=100

#setup the load-balancer
worker.loadbalancer.type=lb
worker.loadbalancer.balance_workers=instance-1,instance-2
worker.loadbalancer.sticky_session=True
#worker.loadbalancer.sticky_session_force=True

# Status worker for managing load balancer
worker.status.type=jk-status
```

here is the /etc/apache2/mods-available/jk.conf

```
<IfModule jk_module>
    JkWorkersFile /etc/apache2/workers.properties

    JkLogFile /var/log/apache2/mod_jk.log

    JkLogLevel info

    JkShmFile /var/log/apache2/jk-runtime-status

    JkWatchdogInterval 60

    <Location /jk-status>
    # Inside Location we can omit the URL in JkMount
    JkMount jk-status
    Order deny,allow
    Deny from all
    Allow from 127.0.0.1 xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
    </Location>
    <Location /jk-manager>
    # Inside Location we can omit the URL in JkMount
    JkMount jk-manager
    Order deny,allow
    Deny from all
    Allow from 127.0.0.1 xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
    </Location>

    # Example for Mounting a context to the worker "balancer"
    # The URL syntax "a|b" instantiates two mounts at once,
    # the first one is "a", the second one is "ab".
    # JkMount /myapp|/* balancer

    # Example for UnMounting requests for all workers
    # using a simple URL pattern
    # Since: 1.2.26
    # JkUnMount /myapp/static/* *

    # Example for UnMounting requests for a named worker
    # JkUnMount /myapp/images/* balancer

    # Example for UnMounting requests using regexps
    # SetEnvIf REQUEST_URI "\.(htm|html|css|gif|jpg|js)$" no-jk

    # Example for setting a reply timeout depending on the requets URL
    # Since: 1.2.27
    # SetEnvIf Request_URI "/transactions/" JK_REPLY_TIMEOUT=600000

    # Example for disabling reply timeouts for certain request URLs
    # Since: 1.2.27
    # SetEnvIf Request_URI "/reports/" JK_REPLY_TIMEOUT=0
</IfModule>
```

here is my virtualhost

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerAdmin support@myserver.com
  ServerAlias live.myserver.com
  #DocumentRoot /var/www
  ServerName go2.myserver.com
  JkMount /* loadbalancer
  JkMount /status/* jk-status
  JkMount /jk-manager/* jk-status
  #Loglevel warn
  ErrorLog /var/log/apache2/go.myserver_error_log
  CustomLog /var/log/apache2/go.myserver_access_log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

**EDIT:** after few hours of struggling the load balancing itself seems to work. just that i can't access the load balancer manager page via `xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx/jk-status` nor `xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx/jk-manager`. there are also this entries in the `mod_jk.log` file

```
[Mon May 06 13:34:48.633 2013] [9845:139723554592576] [info] init_jk::mod_jk.c (3252): mod_jk/1.2.32 () initialized
[Mon May 06 13:34:48.633 2013] [9845:139723554592576] [error] uri_worker_map_ext::jk_uri_worker_map.c (506): Could not find worker with name 'jk-manager' in uri map post processing.
[Mon May 06 13:34:48.633 2013] [9845:139723554592576] [error] uri_worker_map_ext::jk_uri_worker_map.c (506): Could not find worker with name 'jk-status' in uri map p/var/log/apache2/mod_jk.log
```

**Question 1** : what am i missing? why it doesn't work?

**Question 2** : is the `#DocumentRoot /var/www` really necessary?

**Question 3** : what is the difference between the `JkMount` in the `IfModule` of the jk.conf file and the `JkMount` from the `virtualhost`

Kindly help me set this up correctly. thanks

Comment: Well, re: **Question 2**, Things following a `#` in Apache configuration files are comments (i.e. as far as Apache is concerned they don't exist). So no, anything following a `#` is not *necessary* unless it contributes in some way to your understanding of the contents of the file.

Comment: @voretaq7 i commented it out myself because as far as am concerned it's useless in my case. if you check the link of the tutorial i was following DocumentRoot was uncommented. THanks